# #include <exception> - No such file or directory

Tags: android, c++, gcc, gnutls

I am currently trying compiling GnuTLS (for wget) for Android with the Android cross-compile toolchain.

I already fixed many missing-library errors, but now I get the error

> ./includes/gnutls/gnutlsxx.h:26:21: fatal error: exception: No such file or directory
>
> `#include <exception>`

I am using "arm-linux-androideabi-gcc (GCC) 4.9 20140827 (prerelease)" and am using this script https://gist.github.com/z3ntu/57b95b02ebe8e153d5a8 for settings up the env-variables.

Comment: Can you show the corresponding command line?

Comment: I am using the "android_configure --without-p11-kit" which calls ./configure with extra environment variables, and the error occurs when using "make" @MarcGlisse

Comment: make executes a bunch of commands. In particular, it executes something like `.../g++ some_options some_file.cc`, which causes the error you get. Seeing this line would help. (it might be that `make V=1` is more verbose and shows that command, if plain `make` doesn't).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I solved it myself... (still thanks for the help everybody!)

So for all who wonder how to compile GnuTLS for Android:

- Create a standalone toolchain: Execute `build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-21 --install-dir=<your_directory> --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 --stl=gnustl` from the NDK root dir (maybe `~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/`)
- Compile it with extra `-lgnustl_shared` in your `LDFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to run the following command which will tell you where `gcc`'s pre-processor is.  Then ask that pre-processor here it's looking for C++ header files:

```
gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus -v
```

then tweak your setup accordingly.

Comment: When I call "~/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/cc1plus -v"    the output is https://gist.github.com/z3ntu/7dcbd0006ba58375852e

Comment: try it with `--help -v`

Comment: Do you know what I can do now with this output? At least its more :) https://gist.github.com/z3ntu/7dcbd0006ba58375852e#file-new_output